# How do I iterate in Python?

Tags: python

Is there any way to make this code shorter?

```
price1 = input("\nEnter price here: ")
price1 = int(price1)

price2 = input("\nEnter price here: ")
price2 = int(price2)

price3 = input("\nEnter price here: ")
price3 = int(price3)

price4 = input("\nEnter price here: ")
price4 = int(price4)

price5 = input("\nEnter price here: ")
price5 = int(price5)

price6 = input("\nEnter price here: ")
price6 = int(price6)

price7 = input("\nEnter price here: ")
price7 = int(price7)

price8 = input("\nEnter price here: ")
price8 = int(price8)

price9 = input("\nEnter price here: ")
price9 = int(price9)

price10 = input("\nEnter price here: ")
price10 = int(price10)

total = price1 + price2 + price3 + price4 + price5 + price6 + price7 + price8 + price9 + price10
grand_total = (18 * total /100 + total)

print("\nThe total amount weill equil to", grand_total, "(with 18% V.A.T)")
```

Comment: There is (in fact, there are multiple), but I'd recommend you either spend a lot of time reading about the various mechanisms mentioned in all these answers, or wait till your teacher/professor covers them in class.  Don't be a copy-paste commando.  Also, turning in homework with something that will come up in a Google search is a bad idea.

Comment: @sr2222 - Not every newbie to programming is asking the community to do his homework for him; maybe he's learning it on his own, or supplementing his schoolwork with additional practice, both of which are very commendable. If a question sounds like it might be homework, how about asking the OP nicely before blasting him?

Comment: @dj18 I didn't intend to come of that way, hence the first clause of the first sentence.  My appologies; it probably has something to do with my own experiences with commandos who get paid (and I have to clean up after) at my job...

Comment: thanks for the help and i am learning pyhton i my own time at home i have just started to learn about the for loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an accumulator value:

```
total = 0
for i in range(10):
    total += int(input("\nEnter price here: "))
grand_total = 18 * total / 100 + total
print("\nThe total amount will equal to", grand_total, "(with 18% V.A.T)")
```

Answer (score 11):

```
prices = []  # an empty list
for i in range(10):
    price = int(input("\nEnter price here: "))
    prices.append(price)  # append price to list

total = sum(prices)
```

You can then reference each individual price like `prices[index]`

Comment: How does this answer take into account the VAT?

Comment: @dj18 Where did the question specify taking into account VAT?

Comment: The VAT is exactly the same as in the question. I only gave the short way of getting the prices

Comment: @PenguinCoder - read the last two lines of the OP's code closely.

Comment: @CodeChordsman - may I suggest renaming your variable `grand_total` to `total` to more closely correspond to the OP's variable names, as he uses `grand_total` to imply the total plus the VAT.

Comment: @dj18 I see it specifying the VAT. The question though was *Can I make this code shorter?*, not *How can I make this shorter while tally the VAT* Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Protip: Avoid using `float` to work with money to avoid rounding errors

```
from decimal import Decimal

def get_price():
    return Decimal(input("\nEnter price here: "))

total = sum(get_price() for i in range(10))
grand_total = total * Decimal("1.18")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a generator expression:

```
total = sum( int(raw_input("\nEnter price here: ")) for i in xrange(10) )
grand_total = int(1.18 * total) # intended integer division?
```

Comment: It looks to me like the OP is using Python 3, in which case (1) input will return a string, and (2) integer division isn't a problem.  Hard to be sure, I admit, because beginners often use idioms from the wrong dialect.

Comment: @DSM thanks for the note. On second view the OP actually forces prices and division to be integer only.

Comment: If it _were_ Python2, using `input` like that is insane. You'd need to use `int(raw_input(...))`

Comment: @gnibbler - after consultation of the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input): indeed!